# Enqueueing stylesheets on particular plugin admin pages using WordPress Plugin Boilerplate

Tags: plugin-development

I'm writing a plugin using [WPPB](http://wppb.io), and can't seem to get my CSS to enqueue just on my plugin's admin page.

I've got a function in my class-{plugin}-admin.php file that should enqueue the script. And I can see that it's running with the right file path for the css file, but the script doesn't get enqueued for some reason, and I can't find an error. I put error_logs to confirm that the `jo_page_enqueue_styles` function is in fact only running on the correct pages, but still no stylesheet.

```
public function jo_page_enqueue_styles() {

    error_log('jo_page_enqueue_styles ran');

    error_log('style path is: ' . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/jumpoff-admin-page.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/jumpoff-admin-page.css', array(), $this->version, 'all' );

}
```

This function is run by this hook in class-{plugin}.php inside inside the `define_admin_hooks` function,

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'admin_print_styles-'.'toplevel_page_jumpoff' , $plugin_admin, 'jo_page_enqueue_styles' );
```

Any ideas? Am I going about this all wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to ask on the plugins issues page - https://github.com/devinvinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enqueue using a unique name. Since this is custom page the default is to enqueue styles for the plugin under the same name.

`wp_enqueue_style( {unique name}, ...`

Comment: Ha, I just figured it out, and came here to resolve, and I found this answer. This is exactly what it was. I was using the same name for an earlier enqueue of a general admin stylesheet.